# Cloudinary & Angular: 'cl-transformation' is not known element

Tags: angular, typescript, cloudinary

I would like to add a cl-transformation to an image but I get this error :

> 'cl-transformation' is not  known element

Here is what I tried so far:

**in intro.html :**

```
<cl-image public-id="sample" cloud-name="test" >
    <cl-transformation effect="shadow"><cl-transformation>
</cl-image>
```

**in intro.module.ts** :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IntroPage } from './intro';
import {FileUploadModule } from 'ng2-file-upload';
import { Ng2CloudinaryModule } from 'ng2-cloudinary';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
      IntroPage,
  ],
  imports: [
      IonicPageModule.forChild(IntroPage),
      FileUploadModule,
      Ng2CloudinaryModule    => seems necessary for cl-image
   ]
})
export class IntroPageModule {}
```

Result (OKAY):

```
<cl-image public-id="sample" cloud-name="test" >
</cl-image>
```

but with "cl-transformation" then I get this error:

[image]

**I also tried :**

in app.module.ts :

```
import { CloudinaryModule, CloudinaryConfiguration } from '@cloudinary/angular';
import { Cloudinary } from 'cloudinary-core';

...
imports:[
   CloudinaryModule.forRoot({Cloudinary}, { cloud_name: 'test' } as CloudinaryConfiguration),
]
```

but I get :

> OpaqueToken is not a constructor

**What I finally tried also:**

**in intro.ts:**

```
import {CloudinaryImageComponent} from 'ng2-cloudinary';
```

(the doc says : *This directive allows displaying Cloudinary image and apply transformations* )

but it still doesn't work...

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're mixing Cloudinary's SDK with another external one (https://github.com/ekito/ng2-cloudinary).
The external one probably doesn't have a  component at all.

If you're using Cloudinary's SDK it should be (assuming Angular 5)
import { CloudinaryModule, CloudinaryConfiguration } from '@cloudinary/angular-5.x';

Comment: yes I saw yesterday that this external one didn't have cl-transformation, it saves time but it's quite limited, thanks anyway for your answer:)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use these newer packages, more advanced and updated to angular 5+

[cloudinary_angular](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular)

[cloudinary-core](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/tree/master/pkg/cloudinary-core)